# Does an Azure Worker Role running node.js restart the node process if it dies?

Tags: windows, node.js, azure, azure-worker-roles

I've created an Azure Worker Role running node.js using the [Windows Azure PowerShell](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/how-to-guides/powershell-cmdlets/). I've successfully deployed my service and am wondering if the Worker Role will restart the process if it were to die. Is that a benefit of using a Web Role and iisnode over a Worker Role?

**Update**

I made a quick test as Golo Roden suggested in his answer and confirmed that an Azure Worker Role does restart the node process if it dies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be true, I don't know.

But it should be very simple to find out: Just write a simple Node.js application that does nothing but react on requests in a simple form and shuts itself down after 60 seconds or so using `setTimeout` and `process.exit();`.

Then deploy it, test it, wait a few minutes, and if it still does work, obviously Azure restarts the process.

PS: It would be awesome if you could post your findings here.

Comment: I edited my original question with the findings. I confirmed that an Azure Worker Role does restart the node process if it dies. Thanks for the suggestion!